# List View button flow Redirect Url

Tags: visual-workflow, list-view, list-button

I have a need to give the ability to the users to create specific type of opportunity from the opportunity related list on the Account.
For that I created a list view button of type url with the url of the flow.
Fields are prefilled according to the Account which is great.
I want to redirect the user at the end of the flow to the newly created opportunity.
So I tried to use the this core action : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5
but this does not work from List view button.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Please paste your component code as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is you can override FINISH button from AURA/LWC component.

1. Need to create custom AURA/LWC component drag drop in flow.
2. Override the functionality of FINISH button from FlowNavigationFinishEvent method.

For more ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation